# repetition of subject in relative clause

Tags: relative-clauses

"The time that gets wasted in conversing, that time will also be saved." is a right sentence?

---

Or it should be: The time that gets wasted in conversing, will also be saved."

Comment: The former sounds poetic, as though the repetition is there to make a point. The latter has the virtue of brevity.  Less is more. (Lose the comma!)

Comment: Only the second one really sounds fluent.  In normal, daily speech, we wouldn't repeat the subject like that.

Answer (score 0):

The relative clause here is **that gets wasted in conversing**.

> The time {that gets wasted in conversing}

is a noun-phrase.

It can be the subject of a verb. But in your example, the noun phrase with the relative clause is rather like a truncated clause without a verb.  It merely presents the subject for consideration. You could punctuate as follows:

> The time that gets wasted in conversing ... that time will also be
>   saved.
>
> or
>
> The time that gets wasted in conversing— that time will also be saved.

The main clause

> that time will also be saved

has  *demonstrative adjective* **that**, determiner **that**, modifying **time**. **that** is not relative-clause-introducing **that** there.

Consider:

> I saw a car hit the man riding on the bike.
>   -- Do you still see the car?
>   Yes. It's **that car** over there, the red one.

The phrase **that time** points back to the time mentioned and qualified in the initial noun phrase, which is just hanging there in space, if you will; the main clause completes the full thought.

As both comments indicate, this is a sort of oratorical or literary or presentational strategy, not something likely to be heard in a typical conversation.

It is as if there were an implicit "And with respect to" at the head of the sentence to put focus on the subject:

> *And with respect to* the time that gets wasted in conversation, that
>   time will also be saved.

Answer (score 0):

The first sentence has an [appositive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apposition).

> a grammatical construction in which two elements, normally noun phrases, are placed side by side so one element identifies the other in a different way.

For instance,

> My sister Jane

or

> Jane my sister

The usage you offer is unusual, even poetical, in cast, and so would be odd in most contexts.